Pipewire wrong profile for audio interface presonus studio 68c
since i have installed ubuntu studio 24.04 with pipewire, my presonus studio 68c isn't configured correct there shoud be 6 channels i/o and there is only 2channel surround, witch isn't correct.
has anybody a solution or simmilar problems and solved ?

Raising this by saying that, yes, i also have this problem. Suspect need to write the necessary driver for the 68C - it is recognised by generically handled (I get surround sound outputs showing in sound settings, for example, and I cannot access inputs other than the two on the front of the device).
